# JSON data unloaded from Snowflake to S3 external stage

Tags: json, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an external Snowflake stage created on S3 and am using that to unload JSON data as .json file from a Snowflake table. The files are getting encrypted when I open the file from S3. When I unload JSON data as a .csv file, the file can be opened and there is no encryption on it.

```
COPY INTO @stage_name/test.json
FROM table 
file_format=(type=json)
SINGLE=TRUE;
```

```
COPY INTO @stage_name/test.csv
FROM table 
file_format=(type=csv)
SINGLE=TRUE;
```

The STAGE_FILE_FORMAT property has been set as CSV.

Could you please advise why the JSON files are getting encrypted and not csv?

Comment: How do you know it's encrypted? What key is it using? Might it be compressed? Can you share the stage DDL?

Comment: I think your issue is caused  as you created a named external stage and specified a file format for it (CSV in your case). Because the file format options were defined for the stage, it isn’t necessary to specify the same file format options in the COPY command. I don't think the file is encrypted but with default option compression is AUTO so your resulted file is probably in a format that cannot be read directly (like binary). Can you download the file and provide a sample of it?

Comment: The compression was set to auto. After setting compression=none in COPY command, I was able to read the file.